# How to fix jshint error Expected '(' before '('. (expected_a_before_b)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jslint, jshint

Here is javascript code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')
  const title = await page.title()
  console.log(title)
  await browser.close()
})()
```

my settings.json inside .vscode folder

```
{
    "jshint.options": {
      "esversion": 8
    }
  }
```

I am using JSLint and my editor is visual studio code 1.47.2

Here is the error I am getting

```
Expected '(' before '('. (expected_a_before_b) jslint(expected_a_before_b) [3,8]
```

[image]

What could be the cause of this jshint error?

Comment: Looking back, you've got ***jshint*** hint options in Visual Studio Code. Are you using JSLint or JSHint? If JSHint, can you try `/*jshint esversion: 8, asi: true */` at the top of the file?

Comment: it is JSHint. I have updated my question accordingly. Tried putting the snippet on top of the code but it didn't work.

Comment: Loading JSHint into VS Code and opening a file with that snippet gives me semi-colon errors initially, and nothing once I change options to `"jshint.options": {"esversion": 8, "asi": true}`. So JSHint seems to work.

Comment: If I load the _JSLint_ extension into VS Code, however, I *do* get the error you report. I think you need to either swap to JSHint in VS Code (and adjust its options accordingly) or my original answer is "right"; JSLint does not yet support `async/await` and it confused by the `await` keyword.

Comment: I had both JSlint, JShint and ESlint installed in visual studio Code. I have disabled JSlint and Eslint and reloaded. Now it works with your code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's because JSLint doesn't support `async/await`.

Here's [an issue that was raised](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/issues/253), and [a patch submitted to fix it](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/pull/251), but it hasn't been merged and the bug, strangely, was closed when the bug's author decided, "I don't care anymore" -- strange b/c Evgeny is usually pretty active and helpful on the JSLint mailing list.

I think your options are to try that patch, not use `async/await`, or, unfortunately, at least for the time being, change linters. You could also file a new issue at JSLint that essentially repeats the earlier one that was closed without a resolution.